# How to change IOS App visual Size in VS2019?

Tags: android, ios

I´m developing a multiplatform app for Android and IOS.

In Android the app fills the whole screen, but in IOS there is a gap between top of the app and the top of  the screen. Same at the bottom.

When I switch the safeArea Property there is an additional room at the top. But this streak shrinks the size of the app. the empty space does not change.

What is my Mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you have not set a proper lauchscreen in the xcode
you can set the launcscreen in xcode's LauncScreen.Storyboard and giving constraints for the same.
please give a proper lauchscreen and the app will work fine

Comment: Thank you, it´s possible that my Problem depends on that issue. I tried to set up a launch screen for the launch/splash screen. But nothing than a viewcontroller does exist in the launchscreen.storyboard. What do I have to do?

Comment: Oh. Ok, I got it. I had to set these Storyboards in "Info.plist" under "visual Assets". Thanks again for the hint.

Comment: have you fixed the issue